# How to show a two column DropDown?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I want to show a DropDown that should display two values in two columns. I want in HTML or CSS.

Comment: are you using jquery or another framework or just javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do this with HTML and CSS only. You will have to use script also.

Here is a jQuery based drop down

[mcDropdown jQuery Plug-in v1.2.10](http://www.givainc.com/labs/mcdropdown_jquery_plugin.htm)

You can also check this one

[38 jQuery And CSS Drop Down Multi Level Menu Solutions](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/)

Comment: Examples for multi-column dropdowns always seem to focus menus, rather than a simple, multi-column dropdown with data values for data-entry. Line of business applications need these things all the time, yet nobody ever seems to think about data-entry uses.

Answer (score 2):

Mega-dropdown? Check [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/examples/megadropdowns/completed.html) example; Tutorial [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/03/31/make-a-mega-drop-down-menu-with-jquery/).

Comment: The example page doesn't have dropdown