# Select box two columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show a two column DropDown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027711/how-to-show-a-two-column-dropdown)

I need to have "2 columns" in my select box so that the first value aligns correctly.
The image demonstrates the problem:

[image]

The country codes are not aligned, but since i can't set html elements inside 's i would need some kind of plugin that mimics the selects functionality and let's me decide the structure of each option and its values.

I would prefer a jQuery plugin for this. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you are going to find a plugin for this.

You could try to change the font to Courier, and allocate max number of chars for the codes, 3-4 ?

Then place spaces after the code for (4 - code.length) . Then output the values to the select box.

basically, pseudo code:

```
var lstOfSelectOptionTexts = ...

iterate list

split into codes and country names

str = code + (4-code.length)*spaces + countryName

generateOption(str)
```